# store uploaded images into database laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, api, file-upload

i have a product and i want it to have multiple file, so i made a oneToMany relation between product and images model.
i was able to upload image successfully

```php
    public function uploadFile(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('images'))
        {
            foreach($request->file('images') as $file)
                $file->store('public/images/'. $file->getClientOriginalName());
        }
        return $request->file('images');
    }
```

now images are storage into storage/public/~ i want to them them to database
Here is my store function in ProductController

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required|numeric',
            'description' => 'required',
            'category' => 'required',
            'attribute' => 'required',
            'stocks' => 'required|numeric',
            //'discounts' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);

        $product = Product::create($request->only('name','price','description', 'tag', 'category', 'attribute'));
        
        $product->stocks()->create([
            'quantity' => $request->stocks,
            'product_id' => $product->id
        ]);

        $product->discounts()->create([
            //'discount' => $request->discounts,
            'product_id' => $product->id
        ]);

/*
foreach( $request->file('images') as $file)
            {
                $product->images()->create([
                    'product_id' => $product->id,
                    'file_path'  => $file->hashName()
                ]);
            }
*/

}
```

what should i add to it so i be able to store image into the table

### update

images table schema

```php
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('file_path');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained('products')->onUpdata('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

product table schema

```php
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->double('price');
            $table->string('category');
            $table->string('attribute');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('tag');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: can show both table schema

Comment: Try to add a column called `image` into your products table. And you can store there the path of the file

Comment: @JohnLobo i updated the schema so you can have more undrestanting

Comment: @workservice i don't think that is the solution since i stated i wanted a multiple file upload, i was able to store images into the storage folder, my problem is how do i take the uploaded image and store theme within the product store function

Comment: well, what you can do is change relation to belongsToMany, create a pivot table. Basicly all will it do is foreach image you will upload on products table will create a record on the pivot table. I would also recommend to store them on the public folder, not storage, unless they're sensitive data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some think like below

```
$images=[]; 
    
    foreach($request->file('images') as $file){
        
        $fileName = time().Str::random(8).'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
        $file->store('public/images/'.$fileName);
        $images[]=['file_path'=>$fileName] ;
            
    } 
    
    $product->images()->createMany($images);
```

I hope you have hasmany relationship in product model

Comment: yes i have the relationship set and works, you did not specify in which function should i add this ?

Comment: you can after   $product->stocks()->create([
            'quantity' => $request->stocks,
            'product_id' => $product->id
        ]); this

Comment: i can't see how this will get me the images that 'uploadFile' function stored into the public folder

Comment: you have to store only image name not file in db

Comment: yes the file upload will be in it's own route and that routes calls the 'uploadFile' function

Comment: yes this is my problem, how can i store only image name not file in db

Comment: then you have to pass product id also to identify which product images are those

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233668/discussion-between-jagarkin-and-john-lobo).